# ignorar links a ciertos roles discord

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy tratanto de crear un bot que a ciertos roles de discord ignore cuando intenten mandar links, pero no consigo como hacerlo
al mandar un link me tira un mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo mi codigo:

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    link = ["https://"]
    for word in link:
        if message.content.count(word) > 0:
          

            if message.author.role.id == 8547896:
                
            
                print(f'{message.author}({message.author.id}) link')
                await message.delete()
 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT listo!")
                 

client.run("XxxXxxxXxx")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método `Message.author` devuelve un objeto de tipo `Member`. Y como dice el error, este objeto no tiene atributo `role`.

Recuerda que en Discord se puede tener más de un rol.

Según la [documentacion](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) `member` tiene el atributo roles, que devuelve una lista de objetos de tipo `role` (que representan un rol de Discord).

Para saber si el usuario tiene un rol especifico podrías usar la siguiente función. La diseñe para que recorra la lista de roles y devuelva true cuando encuentre el rol. En caso contrario devolverá `False`.

La función acepta un primer argumento que será un objeto `member`, es decir un usuario de Discord. El segundo el el id del rol buscado.

```
def has_role(member, role_id):
    # obtengo la lista de roles e itero sobre ella.
    for role in member.roles:
        #si la id del rol visitado es igual al id del rol buscado, la funcion retorna true
        if(role.id == role_id):
            return True

    #si no se encontro el rol, retorna False
    return False
```

Esta función deberías de usarla así en tu condición:

```
if(has_role(message.author, 8547896))
```